# Auto-Reply Tweets in Twitter (bot) in simple way or tools?

Tags: twitter, bots

is any possible & simple way to make a twitter bot that will reply to some tweets (depend on search terms) in certain time interval. can anyone help me.

for example twitter.com/shastribot

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you like Ruby, then I suggest using the Twitter gem: https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter
It makes things very easy.

You could then write a script that checks whether there are any replies to the bot and if there are any new ones sends out a message. Then set it up as a cron job running as often as you think is necessary.

There's also the Twitter Bot interface to Twitter, I haven't used it myself but might be worth a look: http://integrum.rubyforge.org/twitter_bot/

Answer (score 0):

You should try [tweebot](https://github.com/caxap/tweebot). It's python micro framework for twitter bots. This lib provides built-in blocks (like Filters, Selectors and Actions) that you can combine to achieve your requirements. For example, next code demonstrates how-to create canonical implementation of "retweet" bot ([more examples](https://github.com/caxap/tweebot/tree/master/examples)).

```py
# Next code demonstrates how to create simple twitter bot that select all
# friends' tweets with your mentiones and retweet they.

import tweebot as twb

def main():
    # Step 1. setup context configuration
    repeater = twb.Context({
        'app_name'        : 'repeater',
        'username'        : '<YOUR ACCOUNT NAME>',
        'consumer_key'    : '<YOUR CONSUMER KEY>',
        'consumer_secret' : '<YOUR CONSUMER SECRET>',
        'access_key'      : '<YOUR ACCESS KEY>',
        'access_secret'   : '<YOUR ACCESS SECRET>',
        'timeout'         : 10 * 60, # 10 min, ensure twitter api limits
        'history_file'    : 'history.json', # don't repeat answered tweets
    })

    # Step 2. enable pretty logging (stdout by default)
    twb.enable_logging(repeater)

    # Step 3. setup chain Selector->Filters->Action
    chain = (
        # Select recently tweets with current user mentions.
        twb.SearchMentions(),
        # Apply several filters to selected tweets:
        twb.MultiPart.And(
            # exclude answered, blocked and own tweets
            twb.BaseFilter,
            # then leave only friends tweets (friends list will be cached)
            twb.UsersFilter.Friends(),
            # and finally, exclude tweets with invalid content
            twb.BadTweetFilter),
        # And now, retweet remain tweets 
        twb.ReplyRetweet)

    # Step 4. start processing 
    repeater.start_forever(*chain)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem is a very good one. You can make use of [twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) to see the available methods.

You can start with a Twitter::REST::Client like following:

```
twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

Then you can you use your ***twitter_client*** for various purpose. For example you can post a tweet to your profile using this:

```
twitter_client.update("I am posting this tweet from my Ruby program")
```

You can get a list of all tweets by providing the twitter username like this:

```
twitter_client.user_timeline("YOUR_TWITTER_USER_NAME").each do |tweet|
  puts tweet.text
end
```

For searching for tweets, take a look at [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets).